# TypeError: TextEncoder is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, supertest

I was trying to run tests using supertest in nodejs and I got this error message

```
ReferenceError: TextEncoder is not defined
```

Then i was advised to locate the file "node_modules/whatwg-url/lib/encoding.js" and add this lines of code at the top

```
const { TextEncoder, TextDecoder } = require("./utils");
```

After i did that, i started getting this message

```
TypeError: TextEncoder is not a constructor
```

please, i am using node version 17.4.0

Comment: 1) Node 17 is not stable, use 16 or 18; 2) Never change anything in node_modules directly.

Comment: I installed version 16 but it is still not working. After installing it, is there anything else i should do?

Comment: Try running `npm install --lockfile-only && npm ci`